# Sum of column when grouped by another column, but with different indexes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
date                total_car_crashes   city_id
01.01               1                   Washington
01.02               1                   Washington
01.03               2                   Washington
01.04               2                   Washington
01.05               2                   Washington
01.06               3                   Washington
01.07               4                   Washington
01.08               4                   Washington
01.01               1                   Detroit
01.02               2                   Detroit
01.03               2                   Detroit
01.04               2                   Detroit
01.05               2                   Detroit
01.06               3                   Detroit
01.07               4                   Detroit
```

`total_car_crashes` is a cumulative counter of the number of car crashes for a given city, up to a given date.

I need a time serie with the cumulative counter of car crashes for the entire nation.

What I'm doing right now is aggregating the table so as to have a unique time serie with the total number of events happened.

```
SELECT
  SUM(total_car_crashes) AS total_car_crashes,
  "date"
FROM Table
GROUP BY "date"
```

This works fine, as long as every time serie has the same start/finish date. However, if one series goes to `01.08`, the event counter for all the others is (as expected but not wanted) zero, rather than the max it reached.

```
01.01               2
01.02               3
01.03               4
01.04               4
01.05               4
01.06               6
01.07               8
01.08               4 // -> should be 8
```

I'd like the events_counter to keep going, rather counting as zero where not available.

Is there any way I can ask sql to use the max value of `total_car_crashes` for a time serie where `date` is not available?

I thought about using a cumulative sum, but `total_car_crashes` is already cumulative!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  I simply do not know how "every time an event on a time serie happens event_number is raised by one, and multiple time series are on the same table" relates to the sample data you have provided.

Comment: What's not clear? In the mock sample data there is an "event_number" that goes up, and 2 time series in the same table. The data in the screenshot is different because it's not the simpler mock sample I've made, it's from the actual database... but the concept is the same.

Comment: How do you tell the two series apart?

Comment: By grouping by event_date. I also have id's in real data, but I don't need them for the aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I've removed references to real data and provided expected VS actual input from the sample mock data. Maybe now it makes more sense.

Comment: But you have multiple series with events on the same day?

Comment: @Shawn, yes, exactly. event_number is the cumulative sum of events happened on one serie. If all series are of the same length, the query provided is sufficient to give me a time series detailing how many events happened across all time series in the table at a given date.

Comment: @Shawn, I've added a "serie_id". Although I don't need it so far, it might be needed to produce a solution to this problem.

Comment: Ok, I've completelly "refractored" the question providing an actual real life example.

Comment: I understand this would be trivial is "total_car_crashes" was not cumulative. Unfortunately, data has been provided to me that it's already like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is complicated and so is the solution.
You need distinct `date`s and `city_id`s to be joined to the table and the maximum values of `total_car_crashes`:

```
select 
  d.date,
  sum(coalesce(t.total_car_crashes, m.max_car_crashes)) total_car_crashes
from (
  select * from (select distinct date from tablename)
  cross join (select distinct city_id from tablename)
) d
inner join (
  select date, max(total_car_crashes) max_car_crashes 
  from tablename
  group by date
) m on m.date = d.date
left join tablename t on t.date = d.date and t.city_id = d.city_id
group by d.date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/un8Ea5SEy75WomSEjdQs96/0).
Results:

```
| date  | total_car_crashes |
| ----- | ----------------- |
| 01.01 | 2                 |
| 01.02 | 3                 |
| 01.03 | 4                 |
| 01.04 | 4                 |
| 01.05 | 4                 |
| 01.06 | 6                 |
| 01.07 | 8                 |
| 01.08 | 8                 |
```